# Vertical space in pdf due to space between text and gather

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing, gather

I use the TeXworks editor along with pdfLaTeX. I like to put a vertical space before starting a `gather` environment for my visual and mental peace. However, this puts a vertical space in the output too

```
%FIRST CASE - VERTICAL SPACE IN PDF OUTPUT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{gather*}
\circ
\end{gather*}

%SECOND CASE - NO SPACE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{gather*}
\circ
\end{gather*}
```

Is there a way I can tell the editor to ignore the vertical space coming before a gather or multiline environment?

Comment: There's a simple but fail-safe rule: Never, ever allow a paragraph break to occur immediately before displayed math material (such as an `equation` environment) or a group of displayed equations (such as a `gather*` environment). All-blank lines in TeX and LaTeX input generate a paragraph break. Get rid of the all-blank line(s), and you'll be doing a lot better. Put differently, do learn how to establish "visual and mental peace" for yourself that doesn't entail inserting unnecessary paragraph breaks.

Comment: @Mico  so I can go for the '%' maybe ;) But I wondered if there was another way and also, possibly, why this happens. To conclude, it's difficult to establish mental peace without a break :)

Comment: white space in tex is not cosmetic formatting as it is in some programming languages, it is an explicit instruction to add white space (and in this case a paragraph) to the output.

Comment: texworks is not involved here, that's just the editor you used to write the source

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the answer, I was just looking for a way to write less "compacted" code, a bit difficult to read, I know it is a bit of a blasphemic question, sorry for this

Comment: `%`  is your friend

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much